# How to use hooks inside setTimeout?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, settimeout, visualization

I have a simple program that generates an array. I have added the functionality of reversing the array on button click, but when I click on the reverse the displayed array is not reverse but stayed as is. I am using `setTimeout` so it can be visualized. Why the visualization is not occuring?

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const Dummy2 = () => {
    const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
    const [length, setLength] = useState(10);

    useEffect(() => {
        generateArray();
    }, [length]);

    const generateArray = () => {
        const temp = [];
        for(let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            temp.push(i + 1);
        }
        setArr(temp);
    }

    const handleLength = (e) => {
        setLength(e.target.value);
    }

    const reverseArray = () => {
        let delay = 1;
        for(let i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const temp = arr;
                const t1 = arr[i];
                const t2 = arr[length - 1 - i];
                temp[i] = t2;
                temp[length - 1 - i] = t1;
                setArr(temp);
            }, delay * 1);
            delay++;
        }
    }

    const printArray = () => {
        console.log(arr);
    }

    const maxVal = Math.max(...arr);
    
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="array-container" style={{height: '50%'}}>
                {arr.map((value, idx) => (
                    <div className="array-element"
                         key={idx}
                         style={{height: `${(value * 100 / maxVal).toFixed()}%`,
                                 width: `calc(${100 / length}% - 2px)`,
                                 margin: '0 1px',
                                 display: 'inline-block',
                                 backgroundColor: 'black',
                                 color: 'white'}}
                    >{value}</div>))
                }
            </div>
            <div>
                <button onClick={() => generateArray()}>New array</button>
                <button onClick={() => reverseArray()}>Reverse</button>
                <button onClick={() => printArray()}>Print array</button>
            </div>
            <div className="slider-container">
                1
                <input type="range" 
                       min="1" 
                       max="100" 
                       onChange={(e) => handleLength(e)} 
                       className="slider" 
                       id="myRange" 
                />
                100
            </div>
            {length}
        </div>
    );
}

export default Dummy2;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `reverseArray` function, you are setting state with each iteration, that causing error there.

You need to reverse array completely and then assign it to state.

> Change you `reverseArray` function like below:

```js
  const reverseArray = () => {
    const temp = [...arr];
    let delay = 1000;
    for (let i = 0; i < length / 2; i++) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        const t1 = arr[i];
        const t2 = arr[length - 1 - i];
        temp[i] = t2;
        temp[length - 1 - i] = t1;
        setArr([...temp]);
      }, delay);
      delay+=1000;
    }
  }
```

Working example:

> [Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-herschel-jzbz5)

#### EDIT

Inserted `timeout` for visualization with `1s` time difference in each iteration.

Comment: What I wanted to achieve is to reverse the array with `setTimeout` function to create an animation. Your answer does reverse the array and display it but not the way I wanted it. I wanted that each swap will be animated.

Comment: @Snirka Check out the demo and answer now

Comment: Thanks, this is what I wanted. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-0xk2w?file=/src/App.js) I have an updated version that I made, there is an animation function that I added. I do not understand why the animation get messed up.

Comment: Move `temp` array from the loop, and add it into `reverseArray` function and pass it into `createAnimation`  via argument. You are assigning temp array on each iteration which is causing issue.  https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-surf-5nq4z

Comment: What is wrong with assigning `temp` on each iteration?

Comment: Previously it was assigned inside the loop.. As you know `setState` is `asynchronous`, so you are assigning the `same default state` to `temp` and doing operation on that.. That's why you are getting `same result` on each iteration. Hence there is no changes on UI

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-0xk2w?file=/src/App.js) I tried another thing, adding sort option. Again for some reason the visualization get messed up and even the array get messed up and sometimes it duplicates values. What am I missing when I am approaching this kind of problems?

Comment: You are doing the same mistake again.. Try to debug the code. Figure out the problem. That's how you will learn more..

Comment: [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/staging-water-0xk2w?file=/src/App.js) I found a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I can propose you :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dummy2 = () => {
  const [arr, setArr] = useState([]);
  const [length, setLength] = useState(10);
  const [reverseIndex, setReverseIndex] = useState(0);
  const [didMount, setDidMount] = useState(true);
  const [shouldReverseArray, setShouldReverseArray] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    generateArray();
  }, [length]);

  useEffect(() => {
    // After clicking on 'reverse' button, reverseIndex is edited. Thus this effect is triggered because it listen to 'reverseIndex'. DidMount is here to prevent triggering the effect when the component is mounted
    if (!didMount) {
      if (shouldReverseArray && reverseIndex < length / 2) {
        setTimeout(() => reverseArray(), 1000);
      } else {
        shouldReverseArray = setShouldReverseArray(false);
        setReverseIndex(0);
      }
    } else {
      setDidMount(false);
    }

  }, [reverseIndex]);

  const generateArray = () => {
    const temp = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      temp.push(i + 1);
    }
    setArr(temp);
  };

  const handleLength = e => {
    setLength(e.target.value);
  };

  const reverseArray = () => {
    const temp = Object.assign([], arr); // Make a copy of your state because it is not mutable
    const tempStart = temp[reverseIndex];
    const tempEnd = temp[length - tempStart];
    temp[reverseIndex] = tempEnd;
    temp[length - tempStart] = tempStart;
    setArr(temp); // Set the new arr
    setReverseIndex(prevState => ++prevState); // Set the new index
  };

  const printArray = () => {
    console.log(arr);
  };

  const maxVal = Math.max(...arr);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="array-container" style={{ height: "50%" }}>
        {arr.map((value, idx) => (
          <div
            className="array-element"
            key={idx}
            style={{
              height: `${((value * 100) / maxVal).toFixed()}%`,
              width: `calc(${100 / length}% - 2px)`,
              margin: "0 1px",
              display: "inline-block",
              backgroundColor: "black",
              color: "white"
            }}
          >
            {value}
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => generateArray()}>New array</button>
        <button onClick={() => {setShouldReverseArray(true); reverseArray()}}>Reverse</button>
        <button onClick={() => printArray()}>Print array</button>
      </div>
      <div className="slider-container">
        1
        <input
          type="range"
          min="1"
          max="100"
          onChange={e => handleLength(e)}
          className="slider"
          id="myRange"
        />
        100
      </div>
      {length}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dummy2;

render(<Dummy2 />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is the [Stackblitz repro](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-usj7s4?file=index.js).

Note that when you change the size of your array, reverse act weirdly, I don't know if it comes from my code or yours, i'll try to figure out.

Also, if you don't need to display each changes, you could use `.reverse()` that would be really easier.

---

[Edit] : Ok the bug come from the fact that reverseIndex is not reseted. I edited the code to add the 'shouldReverseArray' state. I call it in the 'onClick' event in the jsx. Pretty dirty, but i can't think about something else here. Hope it helps tho :)